# How to avoid double divide in loop?

Tags: javascript, html, loops, divide

Thank you for your help.

My code looks like:

```
var CatItems = "";

for(var x=0; x < data.PRODUCTS.length; x++) {
if (x % 3 === 0) CatItems += '<li class="jcarousel-item jcarousel-item-horizontal jcarousel-item-'+[x]+' jcarousel-item-'+[x]+'-horizontal jcarousel-item-placeholder jcarousel-item-placeholder-horizontal">';
CatItems += '<div><a class="large_image" href="#"><img  src="'+ data.PRODUCTS[x].product_img +'" alt="' + data.PRODUCTS[x].product_name +'"></a><h3 class="geo_17_darkbrown">' + data.PRODUCTS[x].product_name +'</h3>';

if ( data.PRODUCTS[x].product_onsale==1 ) {
CatItems += '<img alt="sale" src="assets/images/sale.gif" class="sale"><span class="geo_17_red_linethr">&pound;'+ data.PRODUCTS[x].product_retailprice +'</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="price geo_17_darkbrown">&pound;'+ data.PRODUCTS[x].product_webprice +'</span>';
} else {
CatItems += '<span class="price geo_17_darkbrown">&pound;'+ data.PRODUCTS[x].product_webprice +'</span>';
}

if ( data.PRODUCTS[x].product_COLOURS ) {
CatItems += '<span class="colour">';

 for(var y=0; y < data.PRODUCTS[x].product_COLOURS.length; y++) {

CatItems += '<span><a href="'+ data.PRODUCTS[x].product_COLOURS[y].colours_large +'"><img src="'+ data.PRODUCTS[x].product_COLOURS[y].colours_thumb +'" alt="'+ data.PRODUCTS[x].product_COLOURS[y].colour_name +'" /></a></span>';
}

CatItems += '</span>';
}

CatItems += '</div>';

if (x % 3 === 2) CatItems += '</li>';


}
```

and it generates this:

```
<div class="carousel_00 jcarousel-container jcarousel-container-horizontal" style="position: relative; display: block;">            
  <div class="jcarousel-clip jcarousel-clip-horizontal" style="overflow: hidden; position: relative;">
    <ul class="jcarousel-list jcarousel-list-horizontal" style="overflow: hidden; position: relative; top: 0px; left: 0px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; width: 7890px;">
      <li class="jcarousel-item jcarousel-item-horizontal jcarousel-item-0 jcarousel-item-0-horizontal jcarousel-item-placeholder jcarousel-item-placeholder-horizontal">
        <div>
          <a href="#" class="large_image">
            <img alt="Elena Top" src="assets/images/dress1.gif"></a>
          <h3 class="geo_17_darkbrown">Elena Top</h3>
          <img class="sale" src="assets/images/sale.gif" alt="sale">
          <span class="geo_17_red_linethr">£120
          </span>&nbsp;&nbsp;
          <span class="price geo_17_darkbrown">£100
          </span>
          <span class="colour">
            <span>
              <a href="assets/images/colour.gif">
                <img alt="Black" src="assets/images/black.gif"></a>
            </span>
            <span>
              <a href="assets/images/colour.gif">
                <img alt="Brown" src="assets/images/brown.gif"></a>
            </span>
            <span>
              <a href="assets/images/colour.gif">
                <img alt="Purple" src="assets/images/purple.gif"></a>
            </span>
          </span>
        </div>
        <div>
          <a href="#" class="large_image">
            <img alt="Rachel Dress" src="assets/images/dress2.gif"></a>
          <h3 class="geo_17_darkbrown">Rachel Dress</h3>
          <span class="price geo_17_darkbrown">£120
          </span>
        </div>
        <div>
          <a href="#" class="large_image">
            <img alt="Elena Top" src="assets/images/dress3.gif"></a>
          <h3 class="geo_17_darkbrown">Elena Top</h3>
          <span class="price geo_17_darkbrown">£120
          </span>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="jcarousel-item jcarousel-item-horizontal jcarousel-item-1 jcarousel-item-1-horizontal jcarousel-item-placeholder jcarousel-item-placeholder-horizontal" style="float: left; list-style: none outside none;" jcarouselindex="1">
      </li>
      <li class="jcarousel-item jcarousel-item-horizontal jcarousel-item-3 jcarousel-item-3-horizontal jcarousel-item-placeholder jcarousel-item-placeholder-horizontal">
        <div>
          <a href="#" class="large_image">
            <img alt="Elena Top" src="assets/images/dress1.gif"></a>
          <h3 class="geo_17_darkbrown">Elena Top</h3>
          <span class="price geo_17_darkbrown">£120
          </span>
        </div>
        <div>
          <a href="#" class="large_image">
            <img alt="Elena Top" src="assets/images/dress2.gif"></a>
          <h3 class="geo_17_darkbrown">Elena Top</h3>
          <span class="price geo_17_darkbrown">£120
          </span>
        </div>
        <div>
          <a href="#" class="large_image">
            <img alt="Elena Top" src="assets/images/dress3.gif"></a>
          <h3 class="geo_17_darkbrown">Elena Top</h3>
          <span class="price geo_17_darkbrown">£120
          </span>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="jcarousel-item jcarousel-item-horizontal jcarousel-item-6 jcarousel-item-6-horizontal jcarousel-item-placeholder jcarousel-item-placeholder-horizontal">
        <div>
          <a href="#" class="large_image">
            <img alt="Elena Top" src="assets/images/dress3.gif"></a>
          <h3 class="geo_17_darkbrown">Elena Top</h3>
          <span class="price geo_17_darkbrown">£120
          </span>
        </div>
        <div>
          <a href="#" class="large_image">
            <img alt="Elena Top" src="assets/images/dress3.gif"></a>
          <h3 class="geo_17_darkbrown">Elena Top</h3>
          <span class="price geo_17_darkbrown">£120
          </span>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="jcarousel-prev jcarousel-prev-horizontal jcarousel-prev-disabled jcarousel-prev-disabled-horizontal" style="display: block;" disabled="true">
  </div>
  <div class="jcarousel-next jcarousel-next-horizontal" style="display: block;" disabled="false">
  </div>            
  <div class="jcarousel-control geo_10_darkbrown_capital">          7 products&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;                  
    <a href="#">1</a>                 
    <a href="#">2</a>                 
    <a href="#">3</a>                         
    <a href="#">4</a>                 
    <a href="#">5</a>                 
    <a href="#">6</a>                 
    <a href="#" class="last">7</a>              
  </div>        
</div>
```

It works like it should, put every 3 div's in li. but I have another problem with divide. It divide "x" inside the loop.

For example in JS:

```
<li class="jcarousel-item jcarousel-item-horizontal jcarousel-item-'+[x]+' jcarousel-item-'+[x]+'-horizontal jcarousel-item-placeholder jcarousel-item-placeholder-horizontal">
```

And HTML out is:

```
<li class="jcarousel-item jcarousel-item-horizontal jcarousel-item-0 jcarousel-item-0-horizontal jcarousel-item-placeholder jcarousel-item-placeholder-horizontal"></li>

then

<li class="jcarousel-item jcarousel-item-horizontal jcarousel-item-3 jcarousel-item-3-horizontal jcarousel-item-placeholder jcarousel-item-placeholder-horizontal"></li>

then

<li class="jcarousel-item jcarousel-item-horizontal jcarousel-item-6 jcarousel-item-6-horizontal jcarousel-item-placeholder jcarousel-item-placeholder-horizontal"></li>

etc...
```

What I need is that count goes as 0-1-2-3-4-5-etc, but with divide it goes 0-3-6-etc and jCarousel insert blank li's 1-2, 4-5, 7-8.

How I can avoid "x" divide inside the loop?

Tnak you!

Comment: Please edit the question and indent your code properly. Thanks.

Comment: Don't get the point of how i need to edit question and indent code. Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the expression `(x/3)` instead of `x` where you need an incremental count

Comment: I think you need to convert to an integer too - by default javascript does floating point division, so that would give "jcarousel-item-0.33333333" etc...

Comment: @psmears: true, but x will always be an even multiple of 3 when this value is needed since the values he gets are (0,3,6) and wants (0,1,2), unless I misunderstood something...

Comment: @ignaty: if you feel this is the correct answer you can press the checkmark next to it, so others will see that this question has been answered.

Answer (score 0):

create another variable like i = x / 3; and use that instead of using i..?

Edit @psmears:

he has:

```
if (x % 3 === 0)
   CatItems += '<li class="jcarousel-item jcarousel-item-horizontal jcarousel-item-'+[x]+' jcarousel-item-'+[x]+'-horizontal jcarousel-item-placeholder jcarousel-item-placeholder-horizontal">';
```

so if he would create that variable inside the scope of that *if*-statement, everything should be fine

so should have something like:

```
if (x % 3 === 0)
{
    var i = x / 3;
    CatItems += '<li class="jcarousel-item jcarousel-item-horizontal jcarousel-item-'+i+' jcarousel-item-'+i+'-horizontal jcarousel-item-placeholder jcarousel-item-placeholder-horizontal">';
}
```

Comment: Doesn't javascript do floating point division by default - so that would give "jcarousel-item-0.33333333" etc?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question, but having the square brackets around x in this code seems quite weird to me:

```
'<li class="jcarousel-item jcarousel-item-horizontal jcarousel-item-'+[x]+' jcarousel-item-'+[x]+'-horizontal jcarousel-item-placeholder jcarousel-item-placeholder-horizontal">'
```

Try removing them and see what happens:

```
'<li class="jcarousel-item jcarousel-item-horizontal jcarousel-item-' + x + ' jcarousel-item-'+ x +'-horizontal jcarousel-item-placeholder jcarousel-item-placeholder-horizontal">'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting:

```
y=Math.floor(x/3);
```

just before creating the `<li>`, then use `y` in place of `x` when construction the `<li>`.

Comment: If i doing it in this way, then output is 0-3-3-1-1-2-2.

Comment: Can you post the modified code? You need to set `y` immediately before you use it. And you may need to use a name other than `y` (that was just an example) depending on where it's used in your code (since I notice you also use `y` elsewhere!)

Answer (score 0):

```
if (x % 3 === 0) CatItems += '<li class="jcarousel-item jcarousel-item-horizontal jcarousel-item-'+[x]+' jcarousel-item-'+[x]+'-horizontal jcarousel-item-placeholder jcarousel-item-placeholder-horizontal">';
```

Meaning, you are creating an 'li' element only if the value of 'x divided by 3' equals '0'. Obviously, you will get the count as 0,3,6,9 etc.. Review your if condition and make changes accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (x % 3 === 0) CatItems += '<li class="jcarousel-item jcarousel-item-horizontal jcarousel-item-'+[x]+' jcarousel-item-'+[x]+'-horizontal jcarousel-item-placeholder jcarousel-item-placeholder-horizontal">';
```

What do you expect? This is added to your output only if x is a multiple of 3. Change the condition.

And no, don't create another variable but clean up your code.

Comment: Thank you, but cleaning my first in my life JS code will be a little bit hard :)